# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority - both with docker and with github

Tags: github, docker, x509

`docker build -t oreng/iojs .`

```
INFO[0000] Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/iojs/images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
```

my Dockerfile is

```
FROM iojs:latest
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash developer
WORKDIR /home/developer
USER developer
```

Also `hub create` (using https://github.com/github/hub)

```
Post https://api.github.com/user/repos: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: I solved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319538/issue-with-my-ca-certificates-crt

Comment: I have no idea why but i get it solved removing `RUN apk del git` from the Dockerfile...

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned in [`crypto/x509/root_unix.go`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_unix.go), Go (which is what Docker uses) will check CA certificates in

```
"/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",     // Debian/Ubuntu/Gentoo etc.
"/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt",       // Fedora/RHEL
"/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem",                 // OpenSUSE
"/etc/ssl/cert.pem",                      // OpenBSD
"/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt", // FreeBSD/DragonFly
"/etc/pki/tls/cacert.pem",                // OpenELEC
"/etc/certs/ca-certificates.crt",         // Solaris 11.2+
```

Make sure those files are available and not corrupted.

There can be also [sporadic issue with the CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24928412/6309), as in [this comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6474#issuecomment-47500281):

> because now it works :+1: . It must be a amazon edge isssue

The last thread also includes the following check:

> The user reporting the issue either has non of those files or those files don't include the `rapidssl` cert.
>   We could ask them to send us those files and check if the certificate is included.
>   The user may also try this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 32 -connect index.docker.io:443
```

> If that fails, the certificates are missing.

Regarding GitHub, be aware it is under a massive DDoS attack at the moment, which could have other side-effects beside the certificate issue.

Comment: ls  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -l => `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1964 Mar 26 18:19 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. the output of the openssl command: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10690505/    does it look ok? what should be my next step for investigating it?

Comment: @user3538553 not sure: that would seem to indicate some kind of external error (CDN, network issue, firewall, ...).

Comment: I added more info in this github issue: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6474#issuecomment-87042808

Comment: I created a better question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319538/issue-with-my-ca-certificates-crt

Comment: Alright, the certs are missing so how do I fix that?

Comment: @heez https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319873/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/43729776/6309 should help.

Answer (score 18):

In Ubuntu 16.04 , should work with other versions as well.

Create/copy .crt under `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`:

```
sudo cp installation/certificates/docker-registry.crt \
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates
```

And then run

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

This will add the certificate under `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
and then restart docker:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: can you please give the absolute path of installation/certificates/docker-registry.crt and if it is inside the container or host?

Comment: did we find the path to installation/certificates/docker-registry.crt @JackOfAshes-MohitGawande

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68306585/5214853 @inquisitive

Answer (score 8):

Well I was facing a similar issue. And here is it, where I was:

My Scenario:
Built an Ubuntu VM on Oracle VB, and started building my K8s cluster. The docker fails to pull the calico images. Throwing out below errors:

> Failed to pull image "docker.io/calico/cni:v3.18.2": rpc error [...]
> INFO[0009] Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2: x509: certificate
> signed by unknown authority.

Then I tried to perform a simple 'docker login' to the default registry, which lead me to the same error.

These were the outcomes learnt from, an entire day, reading and learning:

1. you can use a self signed certificate
2. you can get a CA certificate from the official website

TBH, none of the above lessons lead me to eureka!

**So, here is what I did**:

I downloaded the certificate from the actual registry, and added it to `/etc/docker/certs/[registry_domain_name]` and the appended the same to the SSL CA certificate on the server. And guess what, I did give me results. So here are the steps in detail below:

**Step 1**: openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ${DOMAIN}:${PORT}</dev/null2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >ca.crt

*What I Ran: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect registry-1.docker.io:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >ca.crt`*

**Step 2**: sudo cp ca.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/${DOMAIN}/ca.crt

*What I Ran: `sudo cp ca.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/registry-1.docker.io/ca.crt`*

**Step 3**: `cat ca.crt | sudo tee -a /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

**Step 4**: `sudo service docker restart`

**Credits to the blog:** https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/environments/registries/

Comment: This worked for me!  In addition to `registry-1.docker.io` I had to do the same set of commands for `production.cloudflare.docker.com` as well.

Comment: Used this to make it work on  Ubuntu 20.04 and a private registry

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, restarted docker and it was gone.

```bash
sudo service docker restart
```