# Gitlab CI :- Getting pending status after push on the gitlab

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using the `Gitlab-ci` for the creating the build on the push,I have also creating the **`.gitlab-ci.yml`** inside my root directory. With each push the code on the Gitlab , i am getting the following message which are as follow

> **This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners that can run this job.**

I have already enable the **`Shared Runners`** in the Setting getting above problem like Not having active member.

Please check my gitlab-ci.yml file data

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
```

[image]

My all push suspended to create the build , please check it once.

[image]

Even though i have created the runner manually but they become fail to execute and getting following excetion

> ERROR: Job failed (system failure): getting Kubernetes config: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided

Please help me to short out from the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have active `shared-runner`, then try to give the tags of the runner in the .gitlab-ci.yml. Say if the tag for the shared-runner is `dev-ci`, then find below the updated code:

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
  - dev-ci
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
```

Screenshot of the runner tags:

[image]

**Setting up a runner**

Before setting up a runner for your project, you need to first:

1. [Install](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/index.html) gitlab-runner on a server separate than where GitLab is installed.
2. [Register a runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html) [there are 3 types of runners: shared, group and specific runners. Depending on requirement, you can choose which runner to register.]
3. While registering the runner, you need to give **tags** and the type of [runner executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/README.html) you need.
4. After registering the runner, go to **Project >> Settings >> CI/CD >> Runners**, you can see the runner is online. If in case you are using Group or Shared runner, then you need to enable the runner in Project settings.

In your case, you can use **Specific Runner** with **Docker as Runner-Executor** and then, in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` use the tags you provided while registering the runner.

Comment: Hi @Sourav.. I have tried your yml file in my project.But unfortunately getting the same problem like **This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online with any of these tags assigned to them: dev-ci**  Please check it once and let me know..Thanks.... I have created the tag dev_ci...But getting this exception , please https://ibb.co/5RwjTV1check it once

Comment: From where have you created the **runner** like in above **2PxrajYi...**  Please guide me on it Thanks

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I have modified my answer with setting up a gitlab-runner.

Comment: Thanks @Sourav , your suggestions has worked, what I have done create the custom runner **docker** and start it from my terminal then after I get the build as desire..Is it the right for it?  Can you please guide me to create the build with flavouring( Create 2-3 apk at once). Please guide me on it.. Thanks☺️

Comment: So you meant to say you are using docker as an executor ? If the same is true, yeah building custom docker image according to the requirement and running CI then, it is totally correct. But sorry, i didn't understand **create the build with flavouring( Create 2-3 apk at once)** Could you please be more specific.

Comment: Actually , I want to create 3 apk of the same app using Gitlab ci.. currently the apk I am getting is debug..Now I want to create apk in 3 types like production, stage and testing, Are you geting my point

Comment: May be this can help then: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/

Comment: Can you please help me on one doubt that how to create the shared runner of gitlab-ci beacause yet now build which is generating is system dependent means when my system is on then i am getting the build otherwise getting fail while creating the build.Please help me on it ..Thanks

Comment: Have you followed the steps mentioned in gitlab-runner documentation ? Try to install fresh. It should not be case what you are facing. You must have missed something while installing the runner.

Comment: Yes, I have followed all the things as you know there is two runner one is Shared runner and another one is Custom runner..I have created the Custom runner which runs well when my system is on but become fail when my system is off.. I have read about the Shared runner which does well to run the task without any dependency..Please guide me about the Shared Runner of the gitlab..Have you get my point, please let me know for more info..Thanks

Comment: Ok. I will help you. Let me know which executor you want to use with shared runner.

Comment: Whatever you can create.. Thanks 

Comment: Could you please create another question for installing a shared runner. It will better, i will write answer there. Here the comments are increasing. Share the question link here.

Comment: please check my new question on Gitlab CI  https://stackoverflow.com/q/64675170/3946958

Comment: Can you please guide me on Jenkin CI-CD configuration for the android. I just want to config my remote server to create my apk and testing,Please help me on it Thanks

Comment: @Ravindra Could you please create a new question with detailed information regarding the same.

Comment: Can I edit the existing question and shared the link to you

Comment: Please check my latest question on Jenkin https://stackoverflow.com/q/68363485/3946958  Thanks