# Gitlab CI :- How to create the Shared Runner in Gitlab which does not depend on the any system?

Tags: android, gitlab, apk, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have study about the `Gitlab Runner` which are two types one is `Custom Runner` and another one is `Shared Runner`.

I have used the `Custom Runner` like `docker` in the `Gitlab` for creating the `apk` of the **`Android`**. And It works fine and create the build which desired. But in this way i am getting one **problem** is that it depends on my system means when my system is on then my `Custom Runner` works fine but when my system become off then `Gitlab` fail to perform operation because it depends on my system runner.

I have read about the `Shared Runner` which does not depend on anything and perform the operation. I have read the documentation but did not get the proper way to implement it .

Please check my **`.gitlab-ci.yml`** file below

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - dev-ci
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDevelopment assembleProduction assembleStaging
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
```

Please help me on the `Shared Runner` of the `Gitlab`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Steps to register a Shared Runner:**

> Pre-requisite: Gitlab-Runner should have been installed. Follow this document for [Installing Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html)

- Login to Gitlab. Go to **Admin Area** >> **Overview** >> **Runners** >> **Set up a shared Runner manually**

[image]

- Login to the server where runner is installed, either with root user or the user with which you have installed runner (say gitlab-runner). Here, we are registering the runner using root user. Run the below command:

  `gitlab-runner register`
- Fill the following details according to your setup:

  - Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL: **https://example.com/gitlab/**

    (Look for the url in the gitlab under **Set up a shared Runner manually**)
  - Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner: **jiRS-3KxGaEdkLo6tToZ**

    (Look for the token in the gitlab under **Set up a shared Runner manually** )
  - Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner: **my-first-shred-runner**

    (Enter any name for the runner)
  - Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated): **ci-shared,ci-task**

    (Enter any tags you want to associate with the runner)
  - Please enter the executor: docker-ssh, parallels, virtualbox, docker+machine, kubernetes, custom, docker, docker-ssh+machine, shell, ssh: **shell**

    (Enter the executor you need the runner to use, depending on choice of executor you will get other options to fill. Please go through documents of [executors](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/README.html) )

Now, you can see the message runner has been registered.

[image]

You can verify the same in the Gitlab. Go to Gitlab, **Admin Area >> Overview >> Runners >> Set up a shared Runner manually** and you can see the runner has been registered with name **my-first-shred-runner**

[image]

Steps to enable Shared Runner for a project in Gitlab:

1. Go to a Project in Gitlab.
2. Then, in the project page, **Settings >> CI/CD >> Runners >> Shared Runners**
3. Then, click on `Enable shared runners`. Now, you can use the shared runner for Gitlab CI/CD.
4. Use the tags associated with shared runner in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, so that the jobs will run using shared runner.

[image]

Change the tags in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - ci-shared
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDevelopment assembleProduction assembleStaging
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
```

**Steps to register Specific Runner:**

1. Login to Gitlab. Go to the Project and then **Settings >> CI/CD >> Runners >> Set up a specific Runner manually**
2. Next, follow the same steps from step 2 as given above for **Registering Shared Runner**

[image]

Comment: If you want to use docker as an executor, then follow this document https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/README.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I am not getting the **Admin Area** in my Gitlab session to perform this step `Admin Area >> Overview >> Runners >> Set up a shared Runner manually
`

Comment: Are you the admin of gitlab ? As only admins can register shared runner.

Comment: No, I am working in the company which they have created the account for me on it, my Gitlab url be like http://188.3X1X.XX.9X:3XX99/

Comment: Then, you can register specific runner or group runner for your use case. Registering specific runner is same as shared runner.

Comment: can you please guide me on this way?

Comment: Are you taking about the `Set up a specific Runner automatically` and it have one button option which says **Install Runner on Kubernetes**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224077/discussion-between-sourav-atta-and-ravindra-kushwaha).

Comment: Glad that it worked. Could you please be more specific on the requirement ?