# docker-compose pull results in x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm hitting the following error when trying to pull the elastcisearch images from dockerhub.

```
docker-compose pull
Pulling elasticsearch (elasticsearch:2.2.0)...
Pulling repository docker.io/library/elasticsearch
ERROR: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/elasticsearch/images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Failed to run with docker-compose
```

My company has an Intermediate Root CA that I suspect is causing the problem. Any ideas how I should configure Docker to use the company Root CA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062803/docker-error-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority)

Comment: same error but doesn't look like the same issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I resolved the problem by adding the CA root `.crt` file the following directory: `/etc/docker/certs.d/docker.io`

Steps to resolve on `Unbuntu 14:04` with `Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108` and `docker-compose version 1.6.0, build d99cad6`:

- In Internet Explorer browse to [docker.io/library/elasticsearch](http://docker.io/library/elasticsearch) and export the companies Intermediate Root CA cert using `DER` format
- On Ubuntu `mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.io/`
- `cp <cert from step one>.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.io/`
- `service docker restart`
- `docker-compose pull` now works and elasticsearch image downloads

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/

Comment: I had to make the directory with the fully qualified name:  `index.docker.io` as opposed to `docker.io`

Answer (score 8):

1. Export the SSL certificate using Firefox.

   - Hit the URL in Firefox
   - Click on advanced, if you see warning or the lock on the URL bar.
   - Export the certificate(In Details tab)
   - Let's assume the cert file name is **your.ssl.server.name.crt**
2. Copy CA cert to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`.
3. `sudo update-ca-certificates`
4. `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: to extract the cert use this  `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <your_registry>:<proper_port> < /dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > <your_registry>.crt`

Answer (score 1):

On native docker (I'm on a mac), this can be resolved by adding to the insecure registries configuration.
Preferences > Advanced > Insecure Registries

Comment: Interface has changed in the recent versions. Try adding the following in the config json (under _Preferences > Daemon > Advanced_ : 
`{
  "insecure-registries" : ["somehost:5005"]
}`

Answer (score 0):

this might happen on local or user registries that might not have root CA signed certificates (these might be self singed). You can use the following steps use these registries:

1. `sudo systemctl edit docker.service`
2. add the registry like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd <some params...> --insecure-registry <your registry here> <other params...>
```

3. Save the file.
4. Reload the configuration with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
5. Restart Docker with `sudo systemctl restart docker.service`