# Docker : Installing Docker behind a proxy on CentOS 7 : Error while pulling image

Tags: docker, centos7

I'm installing docker on CentOS 7 and i have this issue :

Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/centos/images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

The configuration that i have:

Adding the proxy under /etc/sysconfig/docker file

http_proxy=http://login:Password!@ < mydomain > : < port >

https_proxy=http://login:Password!@ < mydomain > : < port >

[root@localhost ~]#  journalctl -xe

i have this :

https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509 certificate signed by unknown authority

So can anyone help me to find a solution for this issue???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946844/docker-compose-pull-results-in-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority might help.

Comment: Thank you fro your response , but it's about the elasticsearch , and i need the ca.pem that i can use it to resolve the authentication issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue , so i download the certificate of the proxy not of the site that i want to have access, and i put it under

/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors

then i execute : update-ca-trust force-enable && update-ca-trust extract

i restart docker , then every thing worked fine