# Error while running hello-world

Tags: docker

```
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
5b0f327be733: Pulling fs layer
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: error pulling image configuration: G
et https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha
256/05/05a3bd381fc2470695a35f230afefd7bf978b566253199c4ae5cc96fafa29b37/data?Exp
ires=1505372640&Signature=LO9Nt0XkgRBYWohS5zpTJFLWKzikKcF0579euysBEXpTGOT8CsWO5p
JBRUxpp-0HtcNlB7bF4RjbGprTjcUUIgkFs8pE5uY9z6AoBADfE~XyFYOul9alK-uYulne52EnvLkNfh
NQO~xR4Y-whwop79R9tiWZuZl8ueTzas2GFYE_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q: x509: c
ertificate signed by unknown authority.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: I ran the below command.$ docker run hello-world

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062803/docker-error-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority)

Comment: I have seen on Windows sometimes run directly has issues. So use `docker pull hello-world` first and then use run command

Answer (score 1):

Your docker engine is trying to contact the registry and having some sort of CDN, firewall, or corporate proxy issue trying to have a proper "conversation" with the registry. It's pretty similar to being on hotel or public WiFi that has a "walled garden" that hasn't been processed through yet.

Unless you have a persistent network issue, it could be temporal, and as someone else suggested a `docker pull hello-world:latest` may work. If you have a corporate proxy, you may have to make sure the Docker toolbox/Docker for Windows configuration has this proxy configured properly to have network access.